# Build a pivot table using MySQL (edited)

Tags: mysql, database, join, sum, pivot

I have a query to build MySQL pivot table, its not giving me quite what I want. What I want to build is this [image]
And the data in MySQL looks like this

[image]

When I ran my query it produces this which is not what I want

[image]

Here is the query

```
 select
    o.name,
    case when p.name= "Cash" then s.amount end as Cash,
    case when p.name= "M-PESA" then s.amount end as mpesa,
  s.customer_credit
FROM outlet o
INNER JOIN sale s ON s.outlet_id = o.id
INNER JOIN payment_type p ON s.payment_id = p.id`
```

Here is the fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0dcbd78/2

Comment: tables should always be postet as text and a sqlfiddle or dbfiddle example is aöways depreciated

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: I have added the schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are quite close. You just need to turn on aggregation:

```
select
    o.name,
    sum(case when p.name= 'cash' then s.amount else 0 end) as cash,
    sum(case when p.name= 'm-pesa' then s.amount else 0 end) as mpesa,
    sum(s.customer_credit)
from outlet o
inner join sale s on s.outlet_id = o.id
inner join payment_type p on s.payment_id = p.id
group by o.name
```